# What's the best site for asking a question about WHM (WebHost Manager)

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm not 100% sure that Stack Overflow is the best site to ask questions about WHM (WebHost Manager) - behind the scenes of cPanel. For starters, most of the questions on SO are about programming <s>and secondly, in the first 50 questions I found tagged `WHM` *none* of them had been answered!</s> (OK, so it turns out that that when you click on a tag SO by default shows Unanswered questions.) Would Server Fault be better?

Comment: The tab choice is "sticky", so whatever tab you viewed last will be the one you're shown by default the next time. It is certainly a little confusing if you're not expecting it.

Comment: @AnnaLear A veeery good point! I was fooled by this already so often!

Answer (score 2):

I was going to propose [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), but apparently there's only one question there in the [whm] tag. However, there's also a [cpanel] tag that seems to be pretty on point.

Server Fault could also be another option - its [whm] and [cpanel] tags seem to be doing a fair bit better.

Comment: OK, I'll try Server Fault and if I get a good response I'll mark your answer correct! :D

Answer (score -1):

> *" when you click on a tag SO by default shows Unanswered questions"*

No, when you filter by tag, you can see

[image]

Just click one of the other tabs, to see other views than `unanswered`.

If you want to make a tag restricted query, just add your query keywords after the `[<mytag>]` in the search field.

Comment: Helpful, but somewhat irrelevant. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear Not sure, because [tag:WHM] seems to be very specialized for me :P ... Tough there's a number of Q&A found when filtering by this tag.

Comment: Yeah, true. But with a nearly 50% unanswered rate on SO, it seems like finding a more suitable site is a better idea either way.

Comment: @AnnaLear +1 _finding more suitable site_ might certainly be a good idea.